# Different credentials in Spring Boot for app authentication and management authentication?

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-boot

I want to use http basic authentication for my Spring Boot application with one set of credentials and at the same time I want to configure actuator to use a different set of credentials for the management resources (health, env etc). I've read the Actucator documentation where it says that you should be able to set the username and password using the `security.user.name` and `security.user.password` properties. However when I add my custom `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` it no longer seems to be applied. My `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 11)
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String API_USER = "API";
    private static final String ADMIN_USER = "ADMIN";

    @NotNull
    @Value("${security.user.name}")
    private String managementUsername;
    @NotNull
    @Value("${security.user.password}")
    private String managementPassword;
    @NotNull
    @Value("${management.context-path}")
    private String managementContextPath;

    public ApplicationSecurityConfig() {
        super(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
                .addFilter(new WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter())
                .exceptionHandling().and()
                .headers().and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
                .and()
                .securityContext().and()
                .requestCache().and()
                .servletApi().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                      .antMatchers(managementContextPath+"/**").hasRole(ADMIN_USER)
                      .antMatchers("/**").hasRole(API_USER)
                      .and()
                .httpBasic();
        // @formatter:on
    }


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("apiUsername").password("apiPassword").roles(API_USER).
                and().withUser(managementUsername).password(managementPassword).roles(ADMIN_USER);
    }
}
```

I've also tried setting `management.security.enabled` to `false` but then the management resources seem to be open to all despite my effort to protect it above.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how to go about?

**Update**

I see that three events are emitted by Spring from my app:

```
2015-06-10 20:04:37.076  INFO 44081 --- [nio-8083-exec-1] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Wed Jun 10 20:04:37 CEST 2015, principal=<unknown>, type=AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException, message=An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext}]
2015-06-10 20:04:39.564  INFO 44081 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Wed Jun 10 20:04:39 CEST 2015, principal=admin, type=AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null}]
2015-06-10 20:04:39.569  INFO 44081 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Wed Jun 10 20:04:39 CEST 2015, principal=admin, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]
```

But there's only two from hyness sample app:

```
2015-06-10 19:34:10.851  INFO 42714 --- [nio-8083-exec-1] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Wed Jun 10 19:34:10 CEST 2015, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]
2015-06-10 19:34:17.139  INFO 42714 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Wed Jun 10 19:34:17 CEST 2015, principal=manage, type=AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hyness answer worked if I changed:

```
..
.antMatchers(managementContextPath + "/**").hasRole(ADMIN_USER)
.antMatchers("/**").hasRole(API_USER)
```

to

```
..
.requestMatchers(request -> !request.getContextPath().startsWith(managementContextPath)).hasRole(API)
.antMatchers("/**").not().hasRole(API)
.antMatchers(managementContextPath + "/**").hasRole(ADMIN)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you would like to have different configurations for different URLs? The [Multiple HttpSecurity](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity) chapter in the Spring Security reference docs suggests that you should create a security config that has multiple `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` beans (simplified snippet based on your problem and the example in the reference docs):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {

    // variables omitted...

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) { 
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("apiUsername").password("apiPassword")
                .roles(API_USER).and()
            .withUser(managementUsername).password(managementPassword)
                .roles(ADMIN_USER);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)                                                        
    public static class ManagementWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher(managementContextPath+"/**")                               
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN_USER")
                    .and()
                .httpBasic();
        }
    }

    @Configuration                                                   
    public static class DefaultWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().hasRole("API_USER")
                    .and()
                .httpBasic()
        }
    }
}
```

Please read the reference docs for details.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either.  DefaultWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter seems to take precedence over ManagementWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter and I can only login to the management resource using the "API_USER" role.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the precedence and changed the management username and password property names and it works for me.  The management context is only accessible to the management user and the rest of the secured paths are only accessible to the **apiUsername**.  The problem is there no basic logout functionality.  You either need to close the browser window or use a private tab to switch users.

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER) 
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String API_USER = "API";
    private static final String ADMIN_USER = "ADMIN";

    @NotNull
    @Value("${management.user.name}")
    private String managementUsername;

    @NotNull
    @Value("${management.user.password}")
    private String managementPassword;

    @NotNull
    @Value("${management.context-path}")
    private String managementContextPath;

    public ApplicationSecurityConfig() {
        super(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.addFilter(new WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter())
                .exceptionHandling().and().headers().and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS).and().securityContext().and()
                .requestCache().and().servletApi().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(managementContextPath + "/**").hasRole(ADMIN_USER)
                .antMatchers("/**").hasRole(API_USER).and().httpBasic();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("apiUsername")
                .password("apiPassword").roles(API_USER).and()
                .withUser(managementUsername).password(managementPassword)
                .roles(ADMIN_USER);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work for me.. I get the same error: "{"timestamp":1433873960313,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Access is denied","path":"/admin/env"}"  What version of spring boot are you using? If I look at the docs (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security) I interpret that the Actuator management username and password properties should be "management.security.user.name" and "management.security.user.password"?!

Comment: Are you using a fresh browser window each time?  You cannot logout without closing the browser window.  If you don't, you will get a 403 because you are logged in as the other user.  I really think this is what is confusing you.  I uploaded my project to github at https://github.com/hyness/basic-security-demo to remove any remaining confusion.  The regular user is user:foobar, the actuator user is manage:woohoo.  You can change those properties through the normal spring boot mechanisms.

Comment: Yes I'm certain that it's not a browser cache issue. I'm clearing all history and restart firefox between every retry. The strange thing is that your example app works very well. When I look at my code and properties (I'm using yaml but it shouldn't matter) they look almost identical but it still doesn't work in my case. I think you deserve the bounty since you've actually answered the question. Unfortunately I still haven't found out what's causing it to fail for me..